# what is the difference between GParsPool.withPool and GParsPool.withExistingPool?

Tags: groovy, gpars, forkjoinpool

what is the difference between GParsPool.withPool and GParsPool.withExistingPool? I didnot understand what was explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While the former creates a thread pool, the latter variant expects a pool instance as a parameter provided by the user.

Vaclav